# How to get the page URL while we calling the ajax function in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page URL and ajax function URL. In my case both are different. But I need to take my current page URL. Is there any way to get the current page URL instead of the ajax URL?
For eg:
My page URL is like this:

```
http://localhost.com/product/654645fgdfdg
```

My ajax URL is like this:

```
http://localhost.com/productpage/get_product_det/654645fgdfdg
```

I need to get the URL like:

```
http://localhost.com/product/654645fgdfdg
```

Comment: Try history.pushstate

Comment: I tried to this but I dint get it

Comment: window.location.href?

Comment: Yes, its working

Comment: I tried to get in php., thats Y

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
var orgUrl = window.location.href;
</script>
```

And I am passing to this URL to a PHP function. Then I got my desired result.